# Как остановить загрузку AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-loader

У меня есть `AsyncTaskLoader`, который загружает и обрабатывает большой объем информации. При выключении приложения мне нужно его остановить (...пока он не съел весь мой трафик). При убийстве процесса он не останавливается (хотя на что я надеялся :)). В `onDestroy` я пробовал писать это:

```
Loader loader = getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID);
if (loader != null) {
    ((AsyncTaskLoader) loader).cancelLoadInBackground();
    getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_ID);
}
```

Но он продолжал загрузку в фоне. Как остановить его?

Comment: Что-то гугл молчит на сей счёт... Может вы после `super.onDestroy()`  его прибиваете?.. Ну и в доках ещё что-то про `onLoaderReset(Loader)` написано - мол оно вызовется если лоадер что-то уже отдавал до уничтожения...

Comment: Метода `onLoaderReset` у меня пустой, я его не использовал. Но он не прибивается — логи идут и идут...

Comment: Ну... А если аццки грязным хаком прибить намертво процесс: `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());`?..

Comment: @bukashka101 А вы в каком методе Activity вызвали метод **initLoader**?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, в обычном закрытом методе, который вызывается в `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Вызовите `AsyncTaskLoader.cancelLoadInBackground()`.

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html#cancelLoadInBackground()

Comment: А где вызывать `cancel(true)`? Ни у `Loader'a`, ни у `supportLoaderManager'a` такого метода нет.

Comment: @bukashka101 смотрите обновление

Comment: Попробовал, но не помогло. Загрузка продолжается.